# Wordpress Contact form 7: can I send 2 different emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I have a contact form where people place an order.
The form sends the order and the information to me, but I would like to make it send a receipt to the customer with some additional information.
Is that possible with contact form 7 and the additional plugins associated with it?

Comment: Have you searched the plugin administration page for any available options?

Comment: Cant seem to find one that supports multiple emails per form, but I might not have searched correctly

Comment: Are you using woocommerce?

Comment: Nope. It is simply a form where people place the order and then are going to be send a mail with order and a number where they send the money. <br> but I would like it to send a mail to myself as well with the order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a few hours! I found that there is a checkbox at the bottom of the mail section, mail (2) [ ]. 
this makes you able to send a second mail

Comment: Thanks, saved me a few hours or more!